# how make `set keymap` only work in insert mode, NOT search

Tags: key-bindings

How do I make sure that my keymap only works in insert mode and nowhere else. Now it also becomes active in search and I don't want this.

A secondary question I also have is: why is my keymap becoming active in denite
search windows. This is regardless of whether my keymap is turned on or off.

Personally, I would like my keymap to work in INSERT mode absolutely nowhere else.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never used `keymap` before, but my understanding of [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'imsearch') is that you should set `imsearch` to `0`

Comment: yo thanks for replying; how do i do this when the keymap is set with `set keymap=...`. I changed the title since I might have been a bit unclear.

Comment: Ah! I didn’t know about that option. I edited the answer, I hop it helps

Comment: cool :) no, that's what is making me confused. setting imsearch to -1 has no effect. and therefore none of the options in mbyte keymap makes any sense to me. I can live with having it work this way but it annoys me a lot that i don't get how it works.

Comment: It is quite confusing. What about `0`? http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'imsearch'

Comment: hmm, now it works. i must have done something wrong earlier. I am quite sure I tried =0 just before making the post. thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: No problem, I learned something new :) For reference I quickly edited the answer